# Magento 2: How to change Tabs to simple order?

Tags: magento2.3

I want to change the detail tabs in the product view page like a simple order.

**Description**

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim.

**More Information**

Activity    Gym, Athletic

Material    Metal, Rubber, Silicone

Gender  Women

Category    Electronic, Exercise, Timepiece

How to change below tabs in simple order as defined above.
[image]

Comment: do you want details first and after more information ?

Comment: yes, I have updated with a new screenshot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override template file details.phtml in your custom theme.

**Path:** `app/design/frontend/[vendor]/[your-theme]/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/details.phtml`

& replace all the code with the below code.

```
<?php if ($detailedInfoGroup = $block->getGroupSortedChildNames('detailed_info', 'getChildHtml')) :?>
    <div class="product info detailed">
        <?php $layout = $block->getLayout(); ?>
        <div>
            <?php foreach ($detailedInfoGroup as $name) :?>
                <?php
                $html = $layout->renderElement($name);
                if (!trim($html)) {
                    continue;
                }
                $alias = $layout->getElementAlias($name);
                $label = $block->getChildData($alias, 'title');
                ?>
                <div>
                     <h3><?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($alias) ?></h3>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <?= /* @noEscape */ $html ?>
                </div>
                <hr>
            <?php endforeach;?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**Just for your info:** By the way, Magento provides the best way to show description & specification in tabs. if you still want to change then you can replace that file code.

**Updated**

To change the title, Go to your catalog_product_view.xml (also override this file) & search for the below code.

```
   <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">More Information</argument>
```

& replace it with.

```
  <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Specification</argument>
```

Comment: thanks, it's working, now i need to change the More information to Specification

Comment: please check my updated answer

Comment: done but not working

Comment: please flush the cache: php/bin magento c:f

Comment: hey, please replace <h3><?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($alias) ?></h3> to   <h3><?= $label ?></h3> in details.phtml & let me know if this is working or not?

Comment: Now I want to change order (specification first & description after specification) & want to move parent div after add to cart.

Comment: please ask another question

Answer (score 1):

you can change this "More Information" to "Specification" using the theme

go to your child_theme/i18n/en_US.csv file

"More Information","Specification"